# Best way to remove redux saga from an old app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, apollo-client

Currently an old app I’m working on uses redux saga for Apollo clients cache, with tons of generator functions that I don’t really understand.

I’m in the process of upgrading from Apollo client 1 to 3.

What would be the best way to rip out redux saga and just use regular mutations throughout the app instead?

Comment: i guess, to learn saga to the point when you understand these functions and is able to replace them with a suitable counterpart. Regardless of that, there should be a solid test coverge to make sure nothing was broken.

Comment: @EstusFlask Sadly there isn't any test coverage, that's something else I'm adding afterwards

Comment: Doing it in the opposite order will be a great help, at least broader ones (integration/e2e).